# subset dataframe based on outlying counts

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe that looks like following:

```
df <- data.frame(Site=rep(paste0('site', 1:5), 50),
           Month=sample(1:12, 50, replace=T),
           Count=(sample(1:1000, 50, replace=T)))
```

I want to remove any sites where the count is always <5% of max monthly count across all sites.

The max monthly counts across all sites are:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(Month), summarise, Max.Count=max(Count))
```

If a count of 1 is assigned to site5, then its counts are always <5% of max monthly counts across all sites. Therefore I would want site5 removed.

```
df$Count[df$Site=='site5'] <- 1
```

However, after assigning new values to site2, some of its counts are <5% of max monthly counts, while others are >5%. Therefore I would not want site2 removed.

```
df$Count[df$Site=='site2'] <- ceiling(seq(1, 1000, length.out=20))
```

How can I subset dataframe to remove any sites where counts are always <5% of max monthly count? Let me know if question unclear and I will amend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a `plyr` solution :

```
## df2$test is true if Count >= max(Count)*0.05 for this month
df2 <- ddply(df, .(Month), transform, test=Count>=(max(Count)*0.05))
## For each site, test$keep is true if at least one count is >= max(Count)*0.05 for this month
test <- ddply(df2, .(Site), summarise, keep=sum(test)>0)
## Subsetting
sites <- test$Site[test$keep]
df[df$Site %in% sites,]
```

Answer (score 6):

A `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(45)
df <- data.frame(Site=rep(paste0('site', 1:5), 50),
       Month=sample(1:12, 50, replace=T),
       Count=(sample(1:1000, 50, replace=T)))
df$Count[df$Site=='site5'] <- 1

dt <- data.table(df, key=c("Month", "Site"))
# set max.count per site+month
dt[, max.count := max(Count), by = list(Month)]
# get the site that is TRUE for all months it is present
d1 <- dt[, list(check = all(Count < .05 * max.count)), by = list(Month, Site)]
sites <- as.character(d1[, all(check == TRUE), by=Site][V1 == TRUE, Site])

dt.out <- dt[Site != sites][, max.count := NULL]
#       Site Month Count
#   1: site1     1   939
#   2: site1     1   939
#   3: site1     1   939
#   4: site1     1   939
#   5: site1     1   939
#  ---                  
# 196: site2    12   969
# 197: site2    12   684
# 198: site2    12   613
# 199: site2    12   969
# 200: site2    12   684
```

Comment: So remove all rows for sites where count <5% max count in Jan, <5% max count in Feb, <5% max count in Mar.... every month of year. Do not remove any rows for sites where, for example, count <5% max count every month except June.

Comment: @RossAhmed, this should do it.